# Acid Rip: DVD not found /dev/dvd

Tags: dvd

I inserted a DVD, and Nautilus shows its `AUDIO_TS` and `VIDEO_TS` folders correctly.
It is making a bit of noise (like seeking/giving up frequently) but I guess it is not the problem.

Problem: Acid Rip says `DVD not found`, and pressing `Load` for `/dev/dvd` does not do anything.

My `/dev/dvd` is a symlink to `/dev/sr0`.

Answer (score 1):

Playing a few seconds of the video with VLC solved the problem.

After using VLC to view the DVD for a few seconds, then closing VLC, I was able to use Acid Rip just by clicking `Load` (still with `/dev/dvd`) and `Start`.

I guess VLC has initialized something that Acid Rip did not do. Or it needed some more time or to be played at least by some player to be used in Acid Rip.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `acidrip` default configuration: `/usr/share/perl5/AcidRip/acidrip.pm`

Near the end of the file you will see the default settings. You can change it from `/dev/dvd` to `/dev/sr0`. Another thing, for me, was `set crop = 0` (off), and `scale = 0` (off).

I am using Ubuntu 13.10, so your mileage my vary.

Comment: OP said `/dev/dvd` is same as `/dev/sr0` in their system.